# execute input jquery event only when there's a pause

Tags: jquery

I have a search input box on a simple form that automatically fetches remote data based on what's entered. **A minimum 3 characters is needed to trigger the search.**

e.g. typing smi will retrieve all staff whose lastname starts with "smi". E.g. Smith, Smithson and etc

I guess my issue is that if I type "Smit", 2 searches are done. I was hoping it is possible to:

1. search only if it meets minimum 3 characters requirement
2. search only if there's a pause

Is this possible? if yes, how?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5or40rLf/7/) .. ***Updated:*** Sorry forgot about the min 3 characters condition and the multi-requests issue

```js
var search, timer;
$('#search1').on('keyup', function () {
    search = $('#search1').val();
    $('#result').html('Min 3 characters');
    if(search.length > 2){ //min char number 3
 clearTimeout(timer);
        $('#result').html('loading..');
 timer = setTimeout(function () {
         $('#result').html(search);
 }, 2000); // time to wait before executing, 2000 milli seconds here
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" id="search1" />
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: thanks for that. I did some testing and while it ignore intermediate keystroke (e.g. I type Smit and it ignored Smi), it run the search multiple times still but only for the final word (e.g. It searched the DB for Smit multiple times). I want it done only once. thanks again

Comment: @mrjayviper, you were right i console.logged and it was making multi requests almost same number as the characters number, I fixed it *according to my test* so please re check it i updated the code

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you use `setTimeout`, and cancel the timeout whenever a key is pressed:

```
(function() {
    var timeout = null;
    var waitTimeMilliseconds = 500; //how many milliseconds the pause must be
    var minLength = 3;
    $("input").on("keydown", function() {
        if (timeout !== null) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
        if ($(this).val().length >= minLength) {
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                lookup();
            }, waitTimeMilliseconds);
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: basically same results as above. The DB search is performed multiple times on the final word I type but it does ignore intermediate words (e.g. I typed "Smit". "Smi" search doesn't happen anymore but "Smit" is performed multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a debounce function. [Lodash](http://devdocs.io/lodash/index#debounce) (and underscore) has one that you can use. Or, if you don't want lodash you could use jquery, or even write your own ([here's a good article](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) on that).

The lodash docs have this to say abo

> Creates a debounced function that delays invoking func until after wait milliseconds have elapsed since the last time the debounced function was invoked

The debounce function should be called on every keystroke, at which point it is reset, but if it isn't called for a specified time it'll trigger the target function. So, you want to call debounce on every keystroke, and set it to wait, say, 100ms, before calling your lookup function.